# Jquery Optimisation of Draggable and Resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm after some help with jquery.  Can some one tell me the best way to optimise the use of the .draggable and .sizable used on many different, but similarly named, elements

for example

```
    $( "#elem1" ).draggable({

        many lines of code
    });

    $( "#elem2" ).draggable({

        many lines of code
    });

    $( "#elem3" ).draggable({

        many lines of code
    });

    $( "#elem4" ).draggable({

        many lines of code
    });

    ...

    $( "#elem1" ).resizable({

        many lines of code
    });

    $( "#elem2" ).resizable({

        many lines of code
    });

    $( "#elem3" ).resizable({

        many lines of code
    });

    $( "#elem4" ).resizable({

        many lines of code
    });

    ...
```

I'm sure there is a way to simply pass the number 1, 2, 3 etc to some multi-purpose code but I'm not sure how to do this since as far as I can see you have to do the elements individually.  I'm sure someone will put me right on this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your `many lines of code` all the same code?

Comment: more or less.  They can be made alike by the inclusion of the Id as 1, 2, 3 and contatenating it to element names...

Comment: Can you provide a link? I'm guessing both the html and the JS can be significantly streamlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code differs only by the strings referring to a specific elements Id, you could reduce your code duplication like this:

```
$("#elem1, #elem2, #elem3, #elem4").resizable({
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); //now you can use the ID without hard coding the string.
});
```

If all your resizable elements share a common class, you could clean this up even further:

```
$(".resizable-element").resizable({
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); //now you can use the ID without hard coding the string.
});
```

If you need to access the integer suffix specifically, you can store that value as a `data` attribute on the element itself:

```
<div id="elem1" data-idSuffix="1" class="resizable-element"></div>
```

To take our example one step further with the markup above:

```
$(".resizable-element").resizable({
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var idSuffix = $(this).data('idSuffix');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, this is just the sort of information I needed as I'm new to the way jquery works.  I'm sure I'll be able to work it out now.

Comment: Nathan, I'm using the first option above.  It works fine for dragging.  It also works for one resize element but since I need different handles for each element the 2nd, 3rd etc don't work as only handles for the first are defined.  Do you know how to set handles differently for each element (in the one piece of code)?  I've tried in the 'create:' event but no joy.

Comment: Post your HTML and the JS you currently have in your question so we can better assist you.  You're drag handle problem will be easier to solve with the "real" markup.

Comment: Nathan, thanks for your reply.  I've managed to solve this by re-writing the html to use the same handles throughout.  I appreciate you taking the time to offer help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your markup, you might be able to use an [Attribute Starts With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("[id^=elem]").draggable({
    // your draggable options...
}).resizable({
    // your resizable options...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a class to all the "elemX"s so that you can target them easily.
2. Use id to get a hold of their "number"
3. Use that number to do whatever you need
4. Profit

If your options truly do depend on the element being instantiated then you WILL need to activate each one independently, but that doesn't mean you can't cut down on your code a bit.

```
$('.yourclass').each(function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
    var num = parseInt( $elem.attr('id').slice(4), 10 );
    $elem.draggable({

        option : "depends on " + num    

    }).resizable({

        option : "depends on " + num    

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sinetheta.  I'll look at this to see if I can arrange my code to do this.